# LIKE CONCAT в LEFT JOIN не срабатывает

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`name` as `t1name`,
    `t2`.`name` as `t2name`
FROM `catalog_1` as `t1`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_2` as `t2`
    ON `t1`.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%',`t2`.`name`,'%')
```

Выбираем из таблицы 2 записи похожие на записи таблицы 1. Вроде все просто. Данные очень простые, типа

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ t1name      + t2name      +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Товар 3 Кр  + Товар 3     +
+ Товар 3 Сн  + Товар 3     +
+ Товар 3 Бл  + Товар 3     +
+ Товар 3 Чр  + Товар 3     +
+ Товар 5 Кр  + Товар 5     +
+ Товар 9 Кр  + Товар 9     +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

// `таблица 1`.`Товар 3 Кр` ~= '%',`таблица 1`.`Товар 3`,'%'
```

Все что выше все нормально, более длинные записи из Таблицы 1 и более короткие записи из таблицы 2

Но если поменять таблицы местами, то запрос не находит в таблице 2 ничего

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`name` as `t1name`,
    `t2`.`name` as `t2name`
FROM `catalog_2` as `t1`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_1` as `t2`
    ON `t1`.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%',`t2`.`name`,'%')

// теперь FROM `catalog_2` as `t1` и LEFT JOIN `catalog_1` as `t2`

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ t1name      + t2name      +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Товар 3     + <NULL>      +
+ Товар 5     + <NULL>      +
+ Товар 9     + <NULL>      +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

И вот тут не понимаю

```
//мне казалось
// `таблица 2`.`Товар 3` ~= '%',`таблица 1`.`Товар 3 Кр`,'%'
```

Подскажите, как написать запрос, что бы SELECT выполнить к таблице 2, с короткими названиями и сопоставить ее с Таблицей 1, с длинными названиями

p.s. исправил свой вопрос, т.к. некорректно выразился

Comment: ну в общем виде должно быть `"длинная строка" like "короткая"`. так что поменяйте колонки в условии местами

Comment: извиняюсь неправильно выразился, в смысле SELECT хочу делать к таблице 2

Comment: *Но если поменять таблицы местами*, то надо это делать везде, а не только в секции FROM. Соответственно получите ``ON `t2`.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%',`t1`.`name`,'%')``.

Comment: Оно! Я просмотрел видимо